# How to have multiple model matrices for multiple 3D models that have been rendered?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have followed the majority of this vulkan tutorial:

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/

I currently have a vulkan program that can load multiple 3D models using OBJ files however I only have one model matrix which controls all of the 3D models, for instance if I load in 2 cubes and then apply a rotation matrix to the model matrix both cubes will rotate.

I want to have a model matrix for each 3D model so that I can rotate, translate and scale then individually.

While following the tutorial I created the following function which is called "UpdateUniformBuffer". This function contains code which applies a rotation matrix to the model matrix every second.

It also uses a struct I created called "UniformBufferObject".

**UpdateUniformBuffer function**

```
void updateUniformBuffer(uint32_t currentImage) {

static auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto currentTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
float time = std::chrono::duration<float, std::chrono::seconds::period>(currentTime - startTime).count(); 

UniformBufferObject ubo{}; 
ubo.model = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), time * glm::radians(90.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));   
ubo.view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
ubo.proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), swapChainExtent.width / (float) swapChainExtent.height, 0.1f, 10.0f);  
ubo.proj[1][1] *= -1;

void* data;
vkMapMemory(device, uniformBuffersMemory[currentImage], 0, sizeof(ubo), 0, &data);
memcpy(data, &ubo, sizeof(ubo)); 
vkUnmapMemory(device, uniformBuffersMemory[currentImage]); }
```

**UniformBufferObject Struct**

```
struct UniformBufferObject {
    glm::mat4 model;
    glm::mat4 view;
    glm::mat4 proj;
};
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://vkguide.dev/docs/chapter-3/push_constants/

Answer (score 4):

There are different approaches, but the most straightforward one that is just an extension of what you already do is having multiple uniform buffers for each object, and separate descriptors for those uniform buffers. At draw time you then bind the appropriate descriptor set for the object to draw that points to it's uniform buffer.

This could look like this:

```cpp
vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(commandBuffer, 0, 1, &vertexBuffer, offsets);
vkCmdBindIndexBuffer(commandBuffer, indexBuffer, 0, VK_INDEX_TYPE_UINT32);
for (Object object : objects) 
{
    vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, pipelineLayout, 0, 1, &object.descriptorSet[currentImage], 0, nullptr);
    vkCmdDrawIndexed(commandBuffer, object.indexCount, 1, object.firstIndex, 0, 0);
}
```

And your object definition may look like this:

```cpp
struct Object {
    uint32_t indexCount;
    uint32_t firstIndex;
    VkBuffer buffer;
    VkDescriptorSet descriptorSet;
};
std::vector<Object> objects;
```

So instead of having just one uniform buffer and one descriptor set that points to it, you create one set for each object and then also update the buffers separate from each other:

```cpp
for (Object object : objects) {
    memcpy(bufferPtr[currentImage], &ubo, sizeof(ubo)); 
}
```

A small note: You don't need to map and unmap your buffers on every frame. You can safely map buffers once after creation ("persistent mapping").

While this may not be the perfect way of having uniform buffers per object it's a good start building on what you learned through vulkan tutorial.

There are other ways of passing data per object, e.g. via the mentioned push constants (which requires command buffers to be rebuild upon change though), but as usual the way to go depends on your use case.

Also note that you want to keep memory/buffer allocations to a minimum due to implementation specific limitations. So if you plan to draw a lot of objects you should look at dynamic uniform buffers or sub allocate instead of allocating separate buffers for each object.

Comment: Do you know of any resources to learn about Dynamic Uniform Buffers?

Comment: I have a sample on this, which also comes with a small tutorial: https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/tree/master/examples/dynamicuniformbuffer